# How to create a separate plug and play blazor class library while having it's reference in main project

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, blazor-server-side, app-config

Currently we have a project, in which there is a component say `SearchComponent` which is injected in another component say `HomeComponent`. Both the components are part of a same project.

Our goal is to separate out the `SearchComponent` into a new `blazor class library` project which will then be referred in the main project.

How can we achieve this in **dotnet blazor-server** application? Can this be done like a plug and play project where in the new project can be referred only if it is specified somewhere in the configuration?